# ¿Es posible realizar consultas a la base de datos en una aplicación en iOS?

Tags: base-de-datos, ionic, ios, sqlite, xcode

Estoy realizando una aplicación para iOS con Ionic 3. Tengo que realizar consultas, inserciones, updates etcetera en la base de datos pero la forma en la que lo estoy haciendo ahora es demasiado lenta.

Para probar cualquier cambio en una consulta por ejemplo un `SELECT * FROM customers` tengo que modificar el código, compilarlo y lanzarlo al dispositivo, abrir la aplicación, hacer login y rellenar un formulario. Como veis es un procedimiento bastante tedioso, podría imprimir por consola esta llamada para que salte al iniciar la aplicación lo cual me ahorraría algo de tiempo pero sigue siendo un proceso lento al tener que volver a compilar y lanzar al dispositivo.

Me gustaría poder hacer llamadas a la base de datos con el dispositivo conectado pero no encuentro la forma. Me pregunto si XCode por ejemplo trae alguna herramienta para conectar con la base de datos. Cuando lanzas la aplicación se genera un servidor interno que debe contener las diferentes vistas y seguro que contiene la base de datos, quizás con el postman podría ser capaz de llamar directamente al servidor de mi aplicación, pero buscando en internet no he encontrado nada claro.

En resumen lo que yo quiero es realizar una consulta como `SELECT * FROM customers` sin tener que estar modificando el codigo fuente y lanzando la aplicación de nuevo.

Comment: Esa BD esta alojada en un servidor o esta en el propio dispositivo? Si esta en un servidor cualquier cliente de BD puede servirte.

Comment: Está alojada en el dispositivo pero creo que las aplicaciones de ionic funcionan con un servidor interno porque cuando intento hacer una llamada desde la aplicación a un servicio web, al hacer el login por ejemplo, el origen de la llamada es `http://localhost:8080` y el origen es el dispositivo. También me aparece su IP si no me equivoco, pero he tratado de acceder desde el ordenador a la IP y me da un 403

Comment: No tengo experiencia en Ionic, pero puedes testear tu aplicación de forma local en tu PC? Porque entonces eso quiere decir que la BD también se genera en tu PC cuando testeas

Comment: Sí y no. Con `ionic serve` se monta una especie de servidor en el PC que emula la app, pero esto no me deja acceder a la base de datos ya que es exclusiva del dispositivo y necesito las funciones de cordova que solo están si hay una plataforma de un dispositivo

Comment: Siento no poder ayudarte entonces, lo único que se me ocurre es que te montes tu una BD local para hacer testeos, con un cliente sql normalmente ya te viene todo preparado.

Comment: El problema es que muchos datos vienen del webservice tras hacer login y no tengo acceso al webservice, solo puedo hacer la llamada y recoger los datos para modificarlos en la app

Comment: Si no te proporcionan una solución mejor, también puedes crear una vista en la app en la que sea un campo de texto y escribir ahí la consulta que quieras y que se ejecute directamente de tal manera que no tengas hardcodeadas las consultas. De todos modos espero que alguien pueda ofrecerte ayuda.

Comment: Es una gran opción no había caído en eso. Es un apaño que puede valer si no hay solución ya que no tengo claro que se pueda conectar con la base de datos del móvil desde fuera pero bueno a ver si alguien sabe mas del tema y quizás sí se pueda. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es descargar el paquete que contiene la base de datos. Para ello:

1. Conecta tu dispositivo al ordenador con el cable.
2. En la barra de menu selecciona Window -> Devices & Simulators
3. Se abrirá una ventana con los datos de tu dispositivo y las apps
   instaladas.
4. Selecciona tu app en la lista
5. Pulsa en el botón del engranaje abajo junto al + [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
6. En el desplegable selecciona Download Container
7. Guarda el archivo donde quieras
8. Click derecho sobre el archivo descargado - > Mostrar contenido del paquete
9. AppData -> Documents ->Encontrarás un archivo **sqlite** con el contenido de la base de datos de tu App guardada en el dispositivo en ese momento

Este método funciona para una aplicación compilada desde Xcode. No para una aplicación descargada desde AppStore o TestFlight

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta!

He de decir que me funcionaron todos los pasos hasta el último ya que en mi caso la ruta donde se encontraba la base de datos era `AppData -> Library -> LocalDatabase`. Muchas gracias

Comment: Si, es posible, porque a partir de ese punto ya depende de cada aplicación. Me alegro de que te haya servido de ayuda.